# Why doesn't Vary: Cookie work in a service worker?

Tags: javascript, cookies, service-worker

In my app, I set a cookie and then call `fetch('/foo', {credentials: 'same-origin'})`. This is intercepted in the service worker which uses `caches` to cache the request and response. The response has `Vary: Cookie` set. Then, I change the cookie and call `fetch` again as above. But when I call `caches.match` in the service worker, the old request is matched! Why is this happening? Can I fix it?

Comment: I don't think service worker has that functionality yet. But when you make the fetch again you can still update the request with the new respone. I don't understand why it won't work. Is it possible for you to paste some part of the snippet?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot comment (low rep) so I am posting here.

Service workers cannot intercept the cookies. There is a proposed [new api in development](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/837) .
Why don't you try to set a custom header for your requests depending on the content of the cookie.

Request 1:
X-Cookie-Value: 1
Vary: X-Cookie-Value

Request 2:
X-Cookie-Value: 2
Vary: X-Cookie-Value